# php foreach: put each of the loop result in one variable

Tags: php, variables, loops, foreach

I think this is probably a very simple but I can get my head around! How can I put each of the loop result in one variable only? for instance,

```
$employeeAges;
$employeeAges["Lisa"] = "28";
$employeeAges["Jack"] = "16";
$employeeAges["Ryan"] = "35";
$employeeAges["Rachel"] = "46";
$employeeAges["Grace"] = "34";

foreach( $employeeAges as $key => $value){
    $string = $value.',';
}

echo $string; 
// result 34,
// but I want to get - 28,16,35,46,34, - as the result
```

Many thanks,
Lau

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use [concatenation...](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
$string .= $value.',';
```

(notice the `.`)...

Comment: How would you remove the last ','

Answer (score 9):

Consider using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) for this specific scenario.

```
$string = implode(',', $employeeAges);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also try

```
$string = '';
foreach( $employeeAges as $value){
    $string .= $value.',';
}
```

I tried that and it works.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach( $employeeAges as $key => $value){
    $string .= $value.',';
}
```

You are resetting your string variable each time through your loop.  Doing the above concatenates $value to $string for each loop iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Um, what about this?

```
$string = "";
foreach( $employeeAges as $key => $value){
    $string .= $value.',';
}
```

You are resetting the variable each time, this starts with the empty string and appends something each time.
But there are propably betters ways to do such tasks, like [implode](http://php.net/implode) in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$string = '';
foreach( $employeeAges as $key => $value){
    $string .= $value.',';
}
```

With $string = $value.','; you are overwriting $string every time, so you only get the last value.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string .= $value.',';
```

Use the [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), put a dot before the equal sign.

You can use this verbose syntax:

```
$string = $string . $value . ',';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this echo must be inside then `{}` became ok

```
    $employeeAges;
    $employeeAges["Lisa"] = "28";
    $employeeAges["Jack"] = "16";
    $employeeAges["Ryan"] = "35";
    $employeeAges["Rachel"] = "46";
    $employeeAges["Grace"] = "34";

    foreach( $employeeAges as $key => $value){
        $string = $value.',';
        echo $string; 

    }

    // result - 28,16,35,46,34, - as the result
```

or other way

```
foreach( $employeeAges as $key => $value){
            $string .= $value.',';

        }
            echo $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Input:**

```
    $array = [1,2,3,4]
```

Save all data in one **string**:

```
    $string = "";
    foreach( $array as $key => $value){
        $string .= $value.',';
    }
```

**Output:**

```
    $string = '1,2,3,4,'
```

Remove **last comma**:

```
    $string =  rtrim($string, ',');
```

**Output:**

```
    $string = '1,2,3,4'
```

More information about:

[concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php);

[rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php).